# Loosing authentication when using SQLServer for storing authentication

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-storage

I was using InProc mode for storing sessions in my mvc3 aplication, but because of the restarting of IIS about every 20 minutes, a changed storing authentication to SQLServer. Connection to database is fine, the session are storing, but authentication doesnt last very long its lost after the restart

Webconfig

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="2880" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
    sqlConnectionString="data source=mydatasource;initial catalog=mydb;user id=userid;password=password;
integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
cookieless="true" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
```

[image: Screenshot of my database]

Comment: Tables and procedures are created by installsqlstate.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out what was the real problem. I had random generator for machineKey, and when the IIS was restarted new machineKey was generated so I couldnt decrypt the auth cookie. The solution is simple -> use static key if you have low level security site

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and Session are 2 completely different things:

1. [`Forms Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)
2. [`ASP.NET Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

It is very important to make the distinction between those. The first is used to track authenticated users on your website. It is configured in the `<authentication>` section in your web.config where you could specify the timeout and validity of the cookie.

ASP.NET Session on the other hand could be used independently. of forms authentication. In your example you seem to be using both in your application. So make sure that they both have the same timeout value.

From what I can see you have set the timeout for your ASP.NET Session to be 2880. Make sure that your forms authentication cookie is also configured to the same amount:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

If you are not using forms authentication but some other mechanism to track your authenticated users, then the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: I added my authentication from webcofig to previous post

Comment: Forms authentication is using cookies to track authenticated users. Those cookies can survive IIS restart because they live on the client. Check with FireBug what happens exactly. Whether a forms authentication cookie is being sent after the restart (normally it should).

Comment: I just checked it, and the cookie is beeing sent